# How to work with the orderbook with R "by" function?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data (let's call it mydata) with the following data frame.

```
datetime|side(0=Bid,1=Ask)| distance(1:best price, 2: 2nd best, etc.)| price
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,1,1.6066
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,2,1.6065
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,3,1.6064
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,4,1.6063
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,5,1.6062

2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,1,1.6067
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,2,1.6068
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,3,1.6069
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,4,1.6070
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,5,1.6071
```

I want to calculate minAsk-maxBid, in this case=1.6067-1.6066. I want to do this for my whole data. I was thinking using "by" but even using this simple code:

```
by(mydata,mydata$datetime, min(mydata$price))
```

to find just the minimum price in each block I get the following error: Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"

Any idea how to implement that? Should I use a different function `ddply` perhaps?

Comment: If you've got "distance" you don't really need min/max; you could just subset to only include `distance==1`.  In fact, if your data are clean, and the spread is never crossed, you can just take the `abs` of the difference of the prices where distance==1 for each time.

Comment: You'll get the best answers if you make your data reproducible.  In this case, if you just provided the output of `dput(mydata)` in your question, you would get better answers.  Note that what you've shown has separate columns for Date and time, but you really should use a single datetime column (probably POSIXct).

Comment: @GSee- I had my data in columns. I will go with the solution in the second answer since sub setting in a huge data is not efficient. Thanks for the points about posting more info, I am new here and I'll do that from thenext time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving `by` the wrong required inputs. You need something like:

```
by(mydata,mydata$datetime, function(x) min(x$price) )
#mydata$datetime: 2008/01/28,09:11:28.000
#[1] 1.6062
```

See `?by` - at it's most basic `by` takes the inputs of...

```
by(data, INDICES, FUN)
```

The function `FUN` is applied to a whole subset of the data.frame specified as `data`. I.e. if you use `identity` as the `FUN` function, each subset defined by `INDICES` will be returned. Try:

```
by(mydata,mydata$datetime, identity )
```

Therefore, you can't just ask for the `min(mydata$price)` directly, you need to ask for the `min` of the `price` variable within the subset. You could write my original answer longhand as...

```
by(mydata,mydata$datetime, function(subdataset) min(subdataset$price) )
```

To expand this to your full problem, you can do something like:

```
by(
  mydata,
  mydata$datetime,
  function(x) min(x$price[x$side==1]) - max(x$price[x$side==0]) 
)
#mydata$datetime: 2008/01/28,09:11:28.000
#[1] 1e-04
```

For future reference, this is very similar in theory to the way the `data.table` package operates with its `by=` argument and its `.SD` (sub-data) code.
A `data.table` answer in this case is even simpler though:

```
mydt <- as.data.table(mydata)

mydt[,min(price[side==1]) - max(price[side==0]),by=datetime]
#                  datetime    V1
#1: 2008/01/28,09:11:28.000 1e-04

mydt[,list(minmax=min(price[side==1]) - max(price[side==0])),by=datetime]
#                  datetime minmax
#1: 2008/01/28,09:11:28.000  1e-04
```

Comment: the `data.table` approach doesn't require `.SD`. `mydt[,min(price),by=datetime]` is sufficient and preferred

Comment: @mnel - damn, you're right - that weakens my analogy between `by` and `.SD` though  ;-)

Comment: great points, I have used data.table, had no idea it is different. why this is not working then:      mydt[,(min(price[side==1])-max(price[side==0])),by=datetime]

Comment: @mitra - your code works fine using the dataset I created from your example - see my edit.

Comment: @mitra are you sure you have a `data.table` and not a `data.frame`.  Maybe your columns aren't named the same?  If you add the output of `dput(mydata)` to your question we could tell you what's different.

Comment: @GSee- I was working with a bigger data. There was a problem in it, now working.

Comment: @thelatemail: your code to see the differences between data.frame and data.table is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
by(mydata,mydata$datetime, function(d)with(d, min(price[side==1])-max(price[side==0])))
```